# How to test UI for ios and android with same code

Tags: android, ios, webdriver, appium

I am attempting to test an application on iOS and Android, and planning to use the same code for testing. As I read, appium is the tool for this, but I have few questions in order to make things by the book:
 - What is the common selector to use in both platforms? driver.findElement(By. -- common selector -- )
 - Is it recommended to do testing like this?

Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: What kind of test is this????

Comment: UI test for the applications

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to make sure with your team that developers use the same format for both the platforms. It means they use the same ID for every element on both the platforms. This way you can use the same script for both the platforms without changing the Id's or classname.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very general question. It depends upon your AUT (app unter test).
At the moment I'm facing a similar issue.
I use pageObjects and I think I'm going to have pageObjects for iOS and Android, that means, there have to be a kind of [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

`By locator = (systemUnderTest == iOS) ? locatorForIOS : locatorForAndroid;`

On this way i hope there won't be the need to write all tests two times. 
Let's see how it's going to work...